# How to block IP Address using Firewalld after $N Times

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables, gnu, firewalld

I want to know how I could block IP Address using firewalld based on number of times ?

For example: I've a running ssh and i want to set a rule if an ip address tried to connect to my ssh server and if it failed after 3 times, it should be got blocked by Firewalld

So how can i do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need something that monitors your `sshd` server logs and adds the client IP address to the banned list when the number of failures reaches the threshold level. `fail2ban` is the usual tool for this.

More specifically, you'll need a `firewalld`-aware backend component for `fail2ban`, i.e. `fail2ban-firewalld`.

Here is a tutorial for RHEL/CentOS 7: https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/install-fail2ban-on-centos-7-to-protect-ssh-via-firewalld/

If you are using RHEL 8, EPEL has `fail2ban-firewalld` packages for it too. The procedure should be pretty much the same.

The Fedora Project has more details on configuration: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fail2ban_with_FirewallD

Here's a link to the actual fail2ban project, which includes more documentation for integrating fail2ban on various services: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I also recommend fail2ban.  It can use firewalld, and can use ipsets instead of iptables rules, which are much more efficient for network traffic.